# JavaScript library that can select different areas of an image and return the coordinates of the selection

Tags: javascript, images

Is there any library or tool in JavaScript/Angular that can help to select different areas of an `img` element in different shapes (e.g. rectangle, circle, etc.) and can provide the details of the coordinates of the image area selected?